# Momentum of Wind

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, velocity

Is there an actual method to calculate the momentum of wind?
I'm doing an experiment on hurricane shutters, where I have to calculate the minimum momentum to close the hurricane shutter. I need the "actual momentum of wind needed" in order to analyze my data.
According to a website, it says the wind speed should exceed 33.1m/s in order to be categorized as a hurricane.

Comment: Please give additional details of hurricane shutter on which you are experimenting, in particular how it functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a force which will close the shutters and so you will need the rate of change of momentum not just the momentum.

If you consider an area $A$ which is perpendicular to the wind velocity $v$ the rate of transfer of momentum through that area is $\rho A v^2$ where $\rho$ is the density of the air.

You then have to make an assumption as to what happens to the velocity of the air once it has hot the shutters so that you can evaluate the rate of change of momentum.

Comment: Actually $\rho v A$ is the mass flow rate through the area.  The rate of momentum flow through the area is $\rho v^2 A$.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Thanks.  I have made the correction.

Comment: Then how do I know the density of air? Is there a fixed value for it?

Comment: The density of air is tabulated in a lot of places eg http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/general_physics/2_1/2_1_1.html